# How SQL Server interprets active Select from View during View Definition Changes

Tags: sql-server

I need too know how SQL Server handles a Long running SELECT statement on a View during a view definition change.

For example,  Let's say I execute a select statement on this view:

`Select * from View`

At the time of execution, the View is set to:
`Select * from TableA`

Due to maintenance windows, data updates, and other ETL runtimes, the View gets changed to:
`Select * from TableB`
while the Select statement from View is still running.

How does SQL Server see this?
Does SQL Server continue that long running Select from the original definition? or does it stop? Does it restart with the new definition?

Thanks!

Comment: agreed, but this is a case of updating tables without a maintenance window.  It's either a View or a Synonym.  Since Synonym's require Drop to create, we don't know if it'll knock out an active SELECT.  as a result, we are looking at Views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the duration of the long-running query the session will hold a schema stability lock on the view (Sch-S ), altering the view requires an incompatible schema modification lock (Sch-M), and so the ALTER will wait for the SELECT.

Comment: Thank you David.  I forgot to ask.  If TableA and TableB are identical, does that matter? or do we assume that the View will stay with TableA, then the definition changes AFTER the last query runs?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the tables are identity, and yes the ALTER will run after the last query completes.

Comment: Thank you.  This was extremely helpful.